# Google Sheets Partial Match Cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do a partial match of Products (Column B) to DB (Column H). Column B however has many partial names within the cell. The entirety of Column H needs to be searched for a partial match of Column B, if a match is found then the cell name from column H needs to be input into column C.

Link to sample Google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZvIbZQ9zsLd6w1uGgSbQ3v-QFebMYrlQfvdsLCfEwAg/edit?usp=sharing

Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: your column C already holds something... can you provide some example of desired output in your sheet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to look for a substring that would correspond to all the cell values from `H2:H70` in `B2` (and the subsequent values of the column `B`) you will be wanting to use the function [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) that compares a text (in the case below `B2`) with a regular expressing (each of the values from `H2:H70`). If it finds a match then it returns the value of column `H` by using the [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) function and if it doesnt it returns empty.

As we are comparing the range `H2:H70` to `B2` this will return an array of possible matches or not matches (emtpy after the `IF`) and therefore this array must be handled with [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en).

Then we are using [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) to only return the array values that are not empty. This will leave us with an array of values of just the actual matches found (in case there are more than one). As I imagined that you want all the matches in a single cell I am taking all the matches array values and joining them in a single array separated by a space using [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en).

Finally, I am using [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) to return empty in case no matches were found.

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, $H$1:$H$70),$H$1:$H$70,"")),"where Col1 is not null")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, however it appears not to work when there is capitalisation - so it requires an exact match. Could this be reformulated so that it matches against a word ignoring capitalisation and it can be anywhere in the string?